# WPF : is it cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

[edited]

in static class myWork,

```
public static class myWork()
{
    public static SomeWPFCollectionType myGenerate()
    {
        SomeWPFCollectionType myGenerated=new SomeWPFType();
        List<SomeType> myLists=new List<SomeWPFType>();

        for(int i=0 ; i < someCount ; i++)
        {
            myLists.Add(new SomeType(...););
        }

        myGenerated = SomeTypeToSomeWPFCollection(myGenerated);
        return myGenerated;
    }
}

....

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ...

    private void btn1_Click(...)
    {
        this.someControl.someCollection = myWork.myGenerate();
    }

}
```

1. what time that memory clearing of myLists?
2. what time that memory clearing of myGenerated?

when first time, i expected when i call a btn1_click.
but Windows' Task Manager report seems to a memory leak, menifestly.

-edited-

i don't think that my code didn't occure a leak on the myLists. because,

```
        ....

        myGenerated.Unloaded += delegate(...)
        {
             //i breaked here and see a value of myList in the Watch window of VS.
             Debug.write(myList.ToString());      
        }

        myGenerated = SomeTypeToSomeWPFCollection(myGenerated);
        return myGenerated;

        ....
```

when the myGenerated was unloaded, but myList have a still 15 items.

Comment: You can't dispose `myLists` - it's a `List<T>`, which doesn't implement `IDisposable`. Additionally, there are various errors in the code you've provided. Code which doesn't compile can't leak. If you can provide us some *real* code, we can give more information about whether or not there's a leak.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You create a new collection each time your Button it pressed, that does not appear like something one would normally do, as Jon Skeet requested post code that will compile and we can go from there.

Comment: Items will be collected almost arbitrarily by the GC, how many times are you clicking the button? How big is `someCount` and is `SomeWPFType` 'big' and is it disposable?

Comment: i edited. i think my real code is not a point. i'm learning on C# so i need a general information. sorry, thanks.

Comment: People have to start explaining why they down vote

Comment: Removed WPF tag, as nothing in the code or rest of post is specific to WPF.

Comment: what does, "what time that memory clearing of myLists?" mean? The sentence doesn't parse for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector is in charge of freeing unused previouslly allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

> } 1.what time that memory clearing of myLists?

When you click on the button.  This does NOT clear out the previous instance of myGenerated obviously.

> 2.what time that memory clearing of myGenerated?

Your code creates a new instance of myGenerated each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector will free the memory for both myLists and myGenerated when ever it pleases* once those variables are out of scope.

The scope for myLists is only in your static class, while the scope for myGenerated is much larger.

Furthermore, a new instance of myGenerated replaces the old instance when the button is clicked. This makes the old instance free for garbage collection.

So, there is no real memory leak in the code you've provided.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: If you're quite new to programming in general, [scope rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) may help understand scope in C#.
The Garbage Collector in C# is cool in that it automatically manages the freeing of memory, so most of the time you don't have to worry about it; see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) for some more details.
That all being said, if 'SomeWPFCollectionType' implements IDisposable, you can explicitly free/release memory with the '.Dispose' method. Hope this helps!

Comment: @mjk6026 With your most recent update you have added a your 'Debug.write' inside the 'myGenerate' method correct? Since 'myList(s)' is defined inside this method, and you haven't left the scope of that method, 'myList' still exists. If you were to put the 'Debug.write' at the end of 'btn1_click(...)' I imagine that 'myList(s)' would not exist. (In fact, it won't even compile) Hope this helps, I'm not sure because I don't know the "big picture" problem you're trying to solve (ie: what is the reason for trying to find the memory leak, how else do you know you have a memory leak, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see memory leaks in the code you posted. Task Manager just isn't the right tool to check for memory leaks.
The Garbage Collector is not required to *immediately* free all unreferenced objects.

If you really suspect a memory leak, look into sos.dll for debugging.
See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx

In the second code fragment, the delegate captures a reference to the newly created and populated list and will of course dump this list to the debug window.

In short: the code may be OK, but you have to work on your debugging skills.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a static list then only generate it once.  If this is a dynamic then this is NOT the correct solution. If your objective is to bind a control to dynamic content the expose the collection as an ObservableCollection property and bind to it. On your "memory leak" until SomeWPFCollectionType generated by myGenerate() falls out of scope it will not be garbage collected.  If you bind the control to a fresh collection it seems like the old collection should be garbage collected.  I think you code is flawed but I don't see a "memory leak".

```
        private List<DocFieldEnum1row> docFieldEnum1rows;

        public List<DocFieldEnum1row> DocFieldEnum1rows 
        { 
            get 
            {
                if (docFieldEnum1rows == null)
                {
                    docFieldEnum1rows = new List<DocFieldEnum1row>();
                    // code to populate list here                
                }
                return docFieldEnum1rows;
            } 
        }
```